# Creating a motion map in R

Tags: r, maps, data-visualization, motion, googlevis

I'd like to know if it's possible to make a motion map in R. I've done some research on the internet but couldn't find an example where this has already been done. My ultimate goal is to have something with a play button, like this: 
[motion bubble map](http://www.gapminder.org/world/#$majorMode=map$is;shi=t;ly=2003;lb=f;il=t;fs=11;al=30;stl=f;st=f;nsl=t;se=t$wst;tts=C$ts;sp=5.59290322580644;ti=1984$zpv;v=0$inc_x;mmid=XCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj1jiMAkmq1iMg;by=const$inc_y;mmid=YCOORDS;iid=phAwcNAVuyj2tPLxKvvnNPA;by=const$inc_s;uniValue=8.21;iid=phAwcNAVuyj0XOoBL_n5tAQ;by=ind$inc_c;uniValue=255;gid=CATID0;by=grp$map_s;sma=49;smi=2.65$cd;bd=0$inds=;modified=75)

The same question has already been asked around 2 years ago, [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148967/r-and-googlevis-possible-to-make-a-motion-map), here the answer was to use Javascript for this. But as 2 years have passed and I have no knowledge of Javascript, I would like to ask if people already found a different solution for this.

I have looked at the googleVis package for motion charts but didn't find an option to use maps here.
Also, I'm using data on regional level and not on country level as they did in the Javascript example.

Eventually I want a motion map for cases through time (by week of year), like in this map: (it's the map of Sierra Leone)
[image]

My last hope is writing a function to automate the process of plotting the maps by week, and then composing a video from all the images... But I would like to know if I get different options for this in R.

Comment: http://www.analyticsandvisualization.com/2014/01/animated-choropleths-using-animation.html ; http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63751/animated-map-in-r ...

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.